# How to move files WHILE creating their folders. Directory.Method, etc

Tags: c#, file-io

> I've found a python post on this but couldn't "convert" it...

So I already have this:

```
    if (Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*_Items_*.pdf").Any())
    {
        string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*_Items_*.pdf");
        foreach (string path in pdfFiles)
        {
            file = Path.GetFileName(path);
            subString = file.Substring(0, 8);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(targetPath, subString));
        } 
    }
```

So in the code I take letters out of files and create folders with those substrings. How would I also move these files directly to their folder created with their substring?

If else because I make a message that says "No items list found" when there are no files.

Every help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the filename in the target folder? `file`? `file.Substring(8)`?

Comment: @John Multiple files that's why the filename is always different, that's also why I've used substring. But it has always this structure --> ABCD1234... PS: Yes it's `file`..

Comment: Did you look at `File.Move` or `File.Copy` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders))?

Comment: Tip: don't use `GetFiles`. It has to read **all** of the file names into memory first, so even something like `Any()` isn't optimized. Use `EnumerateFiles` instead, which is "streamed" as an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 methods [FileInfo.MoveTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [File.Move()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) to use.

The code can be like with the help of LINQ : Create a directory for each file after a check if the folder exists already.
Then move to the new folder created

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*_Items_*.pdf").ToList();

files.ForEach(f => {
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(f);
    var pathName= fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, 8);

    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(targetPath, pathName));
    if(!directoryInfo.Exists)
       directoryInfo.Create();

    fileInfo.MoveTo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, fileInfo.Name); // think about if file already exist

})
```

Comment: Since you're optimising: you don't need to check if the directory exists first. Anyway, +1

Comment: @John Sorry for the misunderstandings before.. but yes, I meant to create the files like > cheese1234_items_20180903.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you can simply use [`File.Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Move_System_String_System_String_) to move the file.

```
foreach (string path in pdfFiles)
{
    file = Path.GetFileName(path);
    subString = file.Substring(0, 8);
    var targetFolder = Path.Combine(targetPath, subString);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
    // Move the file into the created folder
    File.Move(path, Path.Combine(targetFolder, file));
}
```

Comment: This one worked out aswell! Thanks :) As soon as I hit 15 rep, I'll upvote that :D